# Group Ring over commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$R$ is commutative semiprime ring, $(R,+)$ abelian group without torsion. Then $RG$ is semiprime.

Proof by contradiction. If $x$ is nilpotent element in $RG$, then $x=r_1g_1+r_2g_2+...r_ng_n$. $x^m=0$. I want to conclude from this that some $r_i^m=0$.

But how to do it correct?

So thankful for any comments!